# How to truncate multiple lines while showing strings at the end?

Tags: css, vue.js, overflow

I am currently working on a project which involves a gallery function. This includes displaying file names that can be very long, so it's limited to displaying 2 lines only. While that can be achieved with line clamp and overflow, I'm having trouble with the requirement to always show the file extension at the end of the name.

So instead of

```
longfilename_long
filename_longfi..
```

I need it to be

```
longfilename_long
filename_....jpg
```

I have tried to resort to a more simpler method of just cutting down the filename to a limited amount of characters then add the file extension to the end with this

```
const handleName = (file: File) => {
  let fileName = '';
  const fileExtension = file.name.split('.').pop();

  file.name.length > LIMIT_CHAR
      ? (fileName = `${file.name.substring(0, MAX_CHARACTERS_ALLOWED - fileExtension.length - 1)}....${fileExtension}`)
      : (fileName = file.name);
  return fileName;
};
```

```
<div class="filename-wrap">
    <p>{{ handleName(item) }}</p>
</div>
```

```
.custom-delete-label-isShow {
       margin: auto;
       height: 105px;
       .filename-wrap {
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            overflow: hidden;

            p {
               color: #fff;
               margin: auto;
               font-size: 14px;
               padding: 5px 8px;
               overflow-wrap: break-word;
            }
       }
}
```

But this results in some file names with long, breakable substrings able to by pass the length requirement cause the text got cut off early

[image: as shown here the word 'bomber' got cut off to the next line so while I still have only 30 characters of text a part of the name was hidden by overflow]

I'm not sure how I should approach this problem, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to truncate the filename with an ellipsis? `text-overflow: ellipsis;` (Only Firefox supports using a custom string where you could include the extension with `text-overflow: "[...].jpg";`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but to achieve this bahavior of displaying file names within a character limit while ensuring the file extension is always visible, you can follow this approach:

```js
const handleName = (file) => {
  const MAX_CHARACTERS_ALLOWED = 20; // Adjust this value based on your needs
  const fileName = file.name;
  const fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop();
  const fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length - fileExtension.length - 1);

  let truncatedName = fileNameWithoutExtension;
  if (truncatedName.length > MAX_CHARACTERS_ALLOWED) {
    const truncatedCharacters = MAX_CHARACTERS_ALLOWED - 4 - fileExtension.length;
    truncatedName = `${truncatedName.substring(0, truncatedCharacters)}....${fileExtension}`;
  }

  return truncatedName;
};
```

#### Explanation

- The `handleName` function takes a `file` object as input and returns the modified filename.
- The `MAX_CHARACTERS_ALLOWED` variable represents the maximum number of characters allowed for the displayed filename (excluding the file extension). You can adjust this value based on your requirements.
- The `fileName` variable stores the full filename obtained from the `name` property of the `file` object.
- The `fileExtension` variable is extracted by splitting the `fileName` using the dot (".") as the delimiter and selecting the last element.
- The `fileNameWithoutExtension` variable is obtained by removing the file extension from the `fileName`. It uses the `substring` method with the length of the filename minus the length of the file extension minus 1 to exclude the dot.
- The `truncatedName` variable is initialized with the `fileNameWithoutExtension`.
- If the length of the `truncatedName` exceeds the maximum allowed characters, a truncation is performed. The `truncatedCharacters` variable calculates the available characters for truncation by subtracting 4 (for the "..." ellipsis) and the length of the file extension from the maximum allowed characters. The `substring` method is then used to truncate the `truncatedName` to the calculated length and append the file extension with "..." at the end.
- The modified filename is returned by the function.

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="filename-wrap">
  <p>{{ handleName(item) }}</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
.filename-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filename-wrap p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```